# How to push a new viewController with Transparent Background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to Push New View Controller with Transparent Background on top of one View Controller which is  already shown. I know How to PRESENT but I wanted to PUSH new View Controller.

Comment: Try https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: Use Navigation Controller. Check how to use UINavigationController in AppCoda or any Other sites.

Comment: Can you how you present View Controller?

Comment: Do you want the previous view controller to show always? Or you just want to present the new view controller with push animation?

Comment: @jarora : Yes I wanted to been seen the  previous controller from the new controller having Semi transparency, and I also wants that after this I can push new controllers from, lastly Pushed Controller,

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: As I asked in Question, I kNow how to PRESENT view controller but, I Wanted to Push the new Controller.

Comment: You could present a new controller in this way,And also,the previous controller can be seen at the same time....try....Remember to set the backgroundcolor of the new controller. [r:0 g:0: b:0 a:0.4]

Comment: Don't Want To Present. Wants to PUSH Controller.... Please let me know the Way to Push Controller not to PRESENT..

Comment: Present a new controller with no animation and clear color.Then add a new view to the controller with animation from right to left like 'push effect'

Answer (score -1):

You need to give memory to your **ViewController** and set to **RootController** of **UINavigationController**. After that, you can push it from your current controller...

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```